# Build kernel module for existing binary kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

How can one build a kernel module that loads into an exiting binary kernel?

It seems that loading depends on the `BuildID` stored inside the module, but what is needed to match those? I expect the binary kernel to be the result of some git revision, using a default `.config` (copied from `arch/.../configs`). How can I decide which revision and `.config` is needed to build module that would be accepted by the existing kernel?

It seems that matching the of the ARCH and KERNELRELEASE properties as shown by `uname -a` is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the source code for the current kernel you are running. These are usually packaged separately (you don't mention your distro). However once done you should be able to build the external module against that kernel following the instructions: [Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt;h=3fb39e0116b4c8e42d40009357ed5cf13c1f2888;hb=HEAD)

Comment: But my question just arises from finding a self compiled kernel whose source revision is unclear.

Comment: So the qustion is mostly about what defines those BuildID value, to get all things in place needed to have a matching one.

Comment: @dronus: Ahh if your dealing with self compiled kernels two config settings help a lot: CONFIG_LOCALVERSION_AUTO and IKCONFIG_PROC. The first ensures the full SCM version string is appended to the kernel version reported by uname, the second makes a copy of .config available from /proc. With those two things you should be able to re-create the source tree for which-ever version you are running.

Comment: Thanks! `IKCONFIG_PROC` is really cool. However, it has to be set at compile time, so it can't be used for matching an existing binary kernel with `IKCONFIG_PROC` not set.

Comment: @dronus: sadly it's one of those lessons one learns with hindsight. Good luck in hunting down what it was...